# How to trace request/response when WebJob is deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a console app that is made using Azure Webjob SDK. The app makes calls to 3rd party website and performs some logic (authentication, posting some data, etc).

The app works on local machine just fine, but when I deploy the exact same app on Azure as a WebJob then it's not working as expected. The 3rd party website logs the client out after some requests being made (randomly without any patterns as I see it). No exceptions detected in the app itself. This is very confusing since the code is the same and I'm wondering what's the difference between running on local machine vs running on Azure.

Usually I would use Fiddler to see what's going on with request/response during those website calls. How to do that on Azure? How can I see all the requests/responses made by that app? Are there any tools for it?

Comment: Try using https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console and run your webjob exlicitly from command prompt.   See if any exception and so on.

Comment: Firstly, if it is **continuous WebJobs**, you could enable **[remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugwja-remote-debugging-webjobs)** feature to debug remotely and check whether the request is sent and the response is returned. Secondly, you could log application logs in try-catch blocks, and then you could check the logs and trouble shoot.

Comment: There were some weird issues with remote debugging but I managed to get request logs by adding them manually. Didn't solve the whole problem but at least I'm getting somewhere.

Comment: Can you just try/catch and log http response to debug your webjob on azure ?

Comment: Tried Kudu console to Run *.exe and got the same issue. So it was Azure Sandbox specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for remote debuging, as suggested in the comments. It will let you step through the execution of your code.

You could also enable Application Insights in Azure, integrate it in your webjob, and start collecting logs and detailed diagnostics. This way you will get detailed information about the execution of your webjob.